# OpenMP Распараллелить цикл C++

Tags: c++, openmp

5. Распараллелить цикл:

   ```
   for(i = 2; i < N; i++)
   for(j = 2; i < N; j++)
     A[i, j] = A[i - 2, j] + A[i, j - 2];
   ```

Как эффективно распараллелить. Результаты выходят неверные.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



    int main()
    {
         int n=1000;
         int g = 1;
         int **A = new int*[1000];
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            A[i] = new int[n+1];

         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                A[i][j] = g;
                A[j][i] = g+2;
               // cout << A[i][j] << " ";
                g++;
            }
           // cout << endl;

        }   

    cout << endl;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        int i1, j1;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
            i1 = 0, j1 = 0;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1)
            i1 = 1, j1 = 0;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 2)
            i1 = 0, j1 = 1;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 3)
            i1 = 1, j1 = 1;
        for (int i = 2 + i1; i < n; i += 2)
        {
            for (int j = 2 + j1; j < n; j += 2)
            {
                A[i][j] = A[i - 2][j] + A[i][j - 2];
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = n-2; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = n-2; j < n; j++) {
                cout << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            delete [] A[i];
            delete [] A;
    }`
```

Comment: 5. Распараллелить цикл:
For(i=2;i<N;i++)
For(j=2;i<N;j++)
  A[i,j] =A[i-2,j] +A[i,j-2];

Comment: 1. У Вас опечатка в заголовке вложенного цикла: `for (int j = 2; i<n; j++)` - очевидно, условие должно быть `j < n`. 2. Хорошо бы указывать "характер" переменных для parallel (у Вас там только одна, с которой компилятор может не справиться - массив A - он относится к разделяемым (shared) переменным). 3. У Вас явно видно "зависимость данных" - на одной итерации используете разные индексы (`i` и `i-2`). Это значит, что эти пары элементов массива могут одновременно (или даже просто не вовремя) изменяться в разных потоках и результат Вы получите неверный. Нужно менять алгоритм доступа к элементам.

Comment: Да, опечатку исправила, неверный код отправила. Уже пыталась применять алгоритм чет-нечетной перестановки. Нашла другой алгоритм, все равно неверные данные выводятся.             
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
     for (int k=0; k<2; ++k) 
     {
      int i1 = k/2;
      int j1 = k%2;
      for (int i = 2+i1; i < n; ++i)
      {
       for (int j = 2+j1; j < n; j+=2)
       {
        A[i][j] = A[i - 2][j] + A[i][j - 2];
       }
      }
     }

Comment: Так тоже не выйдет. 1. У Вас только 2 значения для разбивки на потоки, а Вы просите 4 потока. 2. `int i1 = k/2;` - у Вас всегда будет равно 0, т.к. `k <2`.

Comment: @Регина, код с попытками решения стоит добавлять в вопрос (есть кнопочка «править»). Направление верное...

Comment: @Регина, а вот рабочий вариант следовало бы сразу в ответ добавить...

Comment: Так он не работает.

Comment: @Регина, а инициализация матрицы у Вас правильно проходит? Там у Вас что-то очень хитрое сделано. И проверку Вы для нее очень не вовремя делаете - лучше вынесите печать отдельным блоком после инициализации. И еще, У Вас матрица имеет размерность `n x (n+1)` - это так и задумано? или все же должна быть квадратной?

Comment: непонятна логика два раза менять значение в матрице. `A[i][j] = g; A[j][i] = g+2;` Определитесь какие числа нужны.

Answer (score 1):

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        int r, c;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
            r = 0, c = 0;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1)
            r = 1, c = 0;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 2)
            r = 0, c = 1;
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 3)
            r = 1, c = 1;
        for (int i = 2 + c; i < n3; i += 2)
        {
            for (int j = 2 + r; j < n3; j += 2)
            {
                arr1[i][j] = arr1[i - 2][j] + arr1[i][j - 2];
            }
        }
    }
```